# why past simple in this case

Tags: past-tense

> We all agreed from the get-go that we were not going to parody- **as** Lou **had** for 20 years.

Why "had" past simple: does it mean that the reformation of the group came before the duration was over,before Lou stopped to parody(as like a synonymous of while)

or does the author did not want to emphasize the duration ( this part of the sentence was not very important) I think this the right explaination

Comment: Actually, it can be read as: as Lou had [done] for 20 years.  A native speaker "fills that in".

Comment: ok this kind of "structure", does it happen often? In which  other cases can you do the same ?

Comment: It is not past simple: it is past perfect, with the auxiliary (_had_) acting as a pro-verb. _Do_ is often used in this way; other auxiliaries are less common, but do occur.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense if you read "had" as the simple past tense - if it was past tense it would require an object, either following, or taken from earlier in the sentence, but there's no noun phrase that would fit. Instead, as a pro-verb it substitutes for a verb phrase which you can easily find.

Answer (score 0):

- We loved the game as she had [loved the game] in the past.

  - We admired the players as we also had [admired them] in the past.
  - We played piano this year as they had [played piano] last year.
  - We were saying so just then as we had been [saying so] all along.

I'm too tired to formulate an actual rule as I usually do in this forum.

Repetition of the main verb is often avoided after **as** since the auxiliary works just fine.

Here is a general reference on non-repetition of the main verb.

[non-repetition or ellipsis of the main verb](https://www.eltbase.com/notes-442-auxiliary-verbs-ellipsis)